# Which answer do I accept if multiple are correct and work for me?

Tags: discussion

I asked an Adobe Illustrator question and received multiple great answers. It seems to be common that for a given task in Illustrator, there are many ways to accomplish the same thing. That was true for my question.

The answers given are distinct from each other, but equally work well for me.

[Here was the question.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/86517/how-to-get-the-top-left-x-y-coordinate-of-a-text-element-in-ai)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should accept the answer that most accurately answered your question, but assuming there are a number of equal but distinct answers then there are a few ways you could go...

- Choose by score (this is essentially deferring the decision to the community)
- Choose the answer you actually used to solve the problem you had
- Choose the answer you imagine to be most helpful to others
- Choose the earliest answer (not the best metric to be choosing an answer on really)
- Choosing the lowest scored but correct answer a.k.a the sympathy accept (not the best idea IMO, you may be helping the answerer out with +15 rep but you're probably not helping future readers)
- ...pick number out of a hat?

In truth it's completely up to you, but try to pick the most helpful answer (or my answer... choose my answer).

Comment: Hahaha hahaha hahaha, yes!

Answer (score 3):

Your acceptance is your acceptance. You can use whatever metric you like. But this is how I choose:

- I choose the one that answers the question best and is easily understandable, failing that
- I choose the answer with most apparent effort behind it, failing that
- I choose the answer that was answered first.

But its your choice you can toss a coin if you like. But try to accept anyways.

PS: you can up-vote also